# Como ordenar campo varchar com letras e números no sql server

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, query, tabela-banco-de-dados

tenho a seguinte query abaixo e gostaria de ordenar conforme a imagem, porém os número.

```
WITH cteNiveis(IdConta, NivelRec, NomeTab, Caminho, Nivel, Tipo, Status, Nome) AS
    (
        SELECT CO.Id, 1 , CAST(CO.Nome AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS NomeTab, CAST(CO.Nome AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 
               CO.Nivel, TC.Nome AS Tipo, CO.Status, CO.Nome AS apenasNome
        FROM Conta CO INNER JOIN TipoConta TC ON CO.IdTipoConta = TC.Id
        WHERE IdContaPai = 21720
          AND IdCliente = 1125
        UNION ALL
        SELECT C.ID, NivelRec + 1,
            CAST(REPLICATE('----', NivelRec) + C.NOME AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS NomeTab,
            CAMINHO + ' \ ' + C.NOME,
            C.Nivel, TC.Nome AS Tipo,
            C.Status, C.Nome AS apenasNome
            FROM CONTA C
            INNER JOIN cteNiveis CTE ON C.IdContaPai = IdConta
            INNER JOIN TipoConta TC ON C.IdTipoConta = TC.Id 
    )
    SELECT IdConta, (CAST(Nivel as varchar(max)) + ' -' + NomeTab) AS Nivel, Caminho, Tipo, Status, Nome
      FROM cteNiveis 
      ORDER BY Caminho, Nome
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 5)
```

O retorno é esse, espero que tenham conseguido entender.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço desde já a quem puder ajudar.

Note que o campo "Caminho" da tabela está dessa forma:

IPTU \ Quadra "A, B ou C" \ Lote "1, 10, 11,  12, 13, .... 2, 3, 4..."

Eu gostaria que as letras de "QUADRA" e os números de  "LOTE" estivessem na ordem correta (sequencial)..

```
NÍVEL                       CAMIHO

1 - IPTU                   IPTU
2 -- Quadra A              IPTU \ Quadra A
3 --- Lote 1               IPTU \ Quadra A \ Lote 1
3 --- Lote "2"             IPTU \ Quadra A \ Lote "2"
3 --- Lote "3"             IPTU \ Quadra A \ Lote "3"
3 --- Lote "4"             IPTU \ Quadra A \ Lote "4"
```

E assim por diante....

Comment: Não está claro na sua pergunta o que você precisa realmente ordenar

Answer (score 1):

Se a coluna caminho tiver sempre esse padrão, você pode manipular o varchar para converter os números finais em inteiro e assim a ordenação ser correta, segue abaixo um exemplo e observe o *ORDER BY*:

```
DECLARE @teste TABLE (
    nivel VARCHAR(MAX),
    caminho VARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT @teste VALUES
('1 - IPTU', 'IPTU'),
('2 -- Quadra A', 'IPTU \ Quadra A'),
('3 --- Lote 1', 'IPTU \ Quadra A \ Lote 1'),
('3 --- Lote 2', 'IPTU \ Quadra A \ Lote 2'),
('3 --- Lote 3', 'IPTU \ Quadra A \ Lote 3'),
('3 --- Lote 4 ', 'IPTU \ Quadra A \ Lote 4'),
('3 --- Lote 5 ', 'IPTU \ Quadra A \ Lote 5'),
('3 --- Lote 6 ', 'IPTU \ Quadra A \ Lote 6'),
('3 --- Lote 7 ', 'IPTU \ Quadra A \ Lote 7'),
('3 --- Lote 8 ', 'IPTU \ Quadra A \ Lote 8'),
('3 --- Lote 9 ', 'IPTU \ Quadra A \ Lote 9'),
('3 --- Lote 10 ', 'IPTU \ Quadra A \ Lote 10');

SELECT
    nivel,
    caminho,
    patindex('%[0-9]%', caminho),
    (CASE PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', caminho) WHEN 0 THEN caminho ELSE LEFT(caminho, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', caminho) - 1) END),
    ISNULL(STUFF(caminho, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', caminho) - 1, ''), 0)
FROM
    @teste
ORDER BY
    (CASE PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', caminho) WHEN 0 THEN caminho ELSE LEFT(caminho, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', caminho) - 1) END),
    CONVERT(INT, ISNULL(STUFF(caminho, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', caminho) - 1, ''), 0))
```

Comment: Eu havia tentado algo assim, mas o problema é justamente esse, não é uma string (varchar) que está sempre no mesmo formato.. o tamanho varia muito. Alguma outra sugestão?

Comment: Algum padrão precisa ter, se não é impossível. Fiz uma alteração para considerar o padrão de haver a numeração sempre no final, independente da quantidade de caracteres anteriores